# Placeholder variable for table name in fetchAll function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function in `PHP` that uses a SELECT `SQL` query.
I using placeholder variable (?) in the query like this. (this placeholder is for table name in mysql database):

```
protected function _fetchPreviousShiftData($table, $report_time)
{

$query = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE report_date=? and shift=?";
$previousShiftData = $this->_getDbConnection()->fetchAll($query,array($table, date("Y-m-d"), $this->_shiftValue($report_time, 8)));

return $previousShiftData;
}
```

but I have an error in $table variable, how should I use "?" for $table variable?
The error is like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''adsl_support' WHERE report_date='2013-04-06' and shift='18-2'' at line 1' in C:\php_shared_lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228
```

Comment: accept vp_arth's answer and vote him. he is write. I have also voted him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this for table name or fields names...
Only for passed values...

You can make a list of the possibles table names, 
check it and build query with

```
"SELECT FROM `$table`..."
```

if check passed

Comment: I can't understand what it means that you say "if check passed" Can you show me an example?

Comment: for example:
`$valid_tables = array('Users', 'Reports');
if(!in_array($table, $valid_tables)) throw new \Exception('Invalid Table Name');
$query = "SELECT ...
`